# Flex 4: Detect click outside of RichEditableText

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Is there any easy way to detect click outside of RichTextEditable? just like    FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE is used in popups.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to this would be to attach event listeners for MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN and SandboxMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_SOMEWHERE to the systemManager like so:

```
systemManager.getSandboxRoot().addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
systemManager.getSandboxRoot().addEventListener(SandboxMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_SOMEWHERE, onMouseDown);
```

This way you get notified of any mouse down events and you can check to see if the event is happening inside of your RichEditableText component or not.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean the Spark `RichEditableText` component or the Halo `RichTextEditor` but they both dispatch the `FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE` event.

If you have MXML you can listen for it like:

`<mx:RichTextEditor id="myText" mouseDownOutside="mouseDownOutsideFunction(event)" />`

or from ActionScript like:

`myText.addEventListener(FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE,mouseDownOutsideFunction);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this but it only works if RichEditableText is inside a popup
 "Dispatched from a component opened using the PopUpManager when the user clicks outside it"

Comment: Ah I see. What is it you are trying to do? Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this after searching for a similar problem, realise it's rather old, but more for the benefit of others.

You can use the focusOut event on TextInput/RichEditableText. Any click outside of the TextInput/RichEditableText will trigger an event to be dispatched.

So:-

```
<s:RichEditableText id="textInput" focusOut="textInput_focusOutHandler(event)" />
```